# Call a private method from an inlined Advice

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'd like to call a private method of a hot-swapped class from an inlined `@OnMethodEnter` code block. Since the private method is inaccessible from the advice code at compile time I created a static stub method `stubFoo(Aaa)` with the same signature as the instance method `Aaa.foo()` . Then I tried using `MemberSubstitution` to replace calls to `stubFoo()` with the private method `foo()`, but it only replaces the calls in the original code, not in the inlined code.

How do I convince Byte Buddy to generate code that calls `this.foo()`?

Expected output:

```
foo: 10
calling original operate...
foo: 10
```

Actual output

```
stubFoo: 10
calling original operate...
foo: 10
```

_

```
public class TestBB2 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final int a = 1;
        final int b = 2;
        final Aaa aaa2 = new Aaa() {

            @Override
            public int operate(final int a, final int b) {
                final int res = super.operate(a, b);
                return res + (a * b);
            }
        };
        aaa2.number = 10;

        ByteBuddyAgent.install();

        testRedefine(a, b, aaa2);
    }

    private static void testRedefine(final int a, final int b, final Aaa aaa2)
                                                                               throws NoSuchMethodException {

        final Method mtdOperate = Aaa.class.getDeclaredMethod("operate", int.class, int.class);
        final Method mtdFoo = Aaa.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo");
        final Method mtdStubFoo = MyAdviceInterceptor.class.getDeclaredMethod("stubFoo", Aaa.class);

        new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(Aaa.class)
            .visit(
                new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods()
                    .method(ElementMatchers.anyOf(mtdOperate), Advice.to(MyAdviceInterceptor.class)
                    //

                    ))
            //
            .visit(
                MemberSubstitution
                    .strict()
                    .method(ElementMatchers.anyOf(mtdStubFoo))
                    .replaceWith(mtdFoo)
                    .on(ElementMatchers.anyOf(mtdOperate)))
            //
            .make()
            .load(Aaa.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

        System.out.println(aaa2.operate(a, b));
    }

    public static class Aaa {

        private int number;

        public int operate(final int a, final int b) {
            System.out.println("calling original operate...");
            MyAdviceInterceptor.stubFoo(this);
            return number + a + b;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void foo() {
            System.out.println("foo: " + this.number);
        }
    }

    private static class MyAdviceInterceptor {

        static void stubFoo(final Aaa _this) {
            System.out.println("stubFoo: " + _this.number);
        }

        @Advice.OnMethodEnter
        static void operate4(
                @Advice.Argument(value = 0, readOnly = false) int a,
                final int b,
                @Advice.This final Aaa _this,
                @Advice.Local("span") Object span1) {
            span1 = "abc";
            System.out.println("redefined2 entering operate...: " + a + " " + b);
            a = 44;
            stubFoo(_this);
            // _this.foo();
        }

        @Advice.OnMethodExit
        static void operate5(
                @Advice.Return(readOnly = false) int value,
                @Advice.Argument(value = 0, readOnly = false) final int a,
                @Advice.Local("span") final Object span,
                @Advice.FieldValue(value = "number") final int number) {
            System.out
                .println(
                    "redefined2 exiting operate... " + value + " " + a + " " + span + " " + number);
            value = value + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This should work. From the top of my head: switch the application order?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter it really helped! I don't understand the `visit()` javadoc then: `are applied on top of another in their registration order.` . Maybe my English is bad

Comment: It's not that clear as it uses ASM concepts. I'll see to rewrite this.